# Why is there no "Restore" or "put back" button in my trash?

Tags: terminal, finder, folders, macos, trash

There is no restore option when I right click a folder in my trash. Did I do something wrong with my computer to cause it to do away with this option?

[image: The options when I right-click a folder in my Trash]

Comment: How did the folder get there? You can generally only 'put back' if the Finder deleted something, not if a script or app deleted it.

Comment: @Tetsujin now that you mention it, I'm pretty sure I deleted them from the Visual Studio Code app.

Comment: Let me throw together a rough answer, in that case...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover file from Trash](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102650/how-to-recover-file-from-trash)

Answer (score 2):

From comments, it appears the folder may have been deleted by an app/script.

I general, the only time the Put Back flag is created is if the file/folder is deleted in the 'normal' way, by the user themselves, in Finder.

I'm afraid i don't know how it does this or the spec of the tagging it uses - perhaps someone smarter than me could provide analysis on that - I just know this through empiricism.

Comment: [This post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52357/how-to-determine-original-location-of-file-that-is-currently-in-the-trash) touches on how the Finder "knows" where to "Put Back" a file—essentially, it adds an entry to the Trash's `.DS_Store` file. Try running `hexdump -C ~/.Trash/.DS_Store` to see the stored entries (though also note that there are other `.Trash` folders on disk, like in iCloud Drive, that have their own `.DS_Store` but are aggregated by Finder into the one "Trash" view).